# How do I find duplicate lines in multiple files within folders

Tags: linux, bash, find, comm

when i want to find duplicate lines between two files i use this command

```
comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

or

```
sort file1.txt file2.txt | awk 'dup[$0]++ == 1'
```

But, how do I find duplicate lines in multiple files within folders. example:

```
mainfolder
  folder1
    file1-1.txt
    file1-2.txt
    etc
  folder2
    file2-1.txt
    file2-2.txt
    etc
```

and that the result in terminal is displayed by file (that is, the lines repeated in all files but specify which file is the one that contains it) to know the origin of the problem.

PD: I tried [this command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185596/828892) and it didn't work for me

```
file_expr="*.txt"; sort $file_expr | sed 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^\s*$/d' | uniq -d | while read dup_line; do grep -Hn "^\s*$dup_line\s*$" $file_expr; done| sort -t: -k3 -k1,2 | awk -F: '{ file=$1; line=$2; $1=$2=""; gsub(/(^[ \t]+)|([ \t]+$)/,"",$0); if (prev != "" && prev != $0) printf ("\n"); printf ("\033[0;33m%s (line %s)\033[0m: %s\n", file, line, $0); prev=$0; }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this (if no files have a tab caracter in their names):

```
grep -T -r . mainfolder | sort -k 2 | uniq -D -f 1
```

The recursive `grep` will output each line prefixed by the filename it is in. Then you sort based on all the fields but the first one. Finally `uniq` outputs just the duplicated lines, skipping the first field.

You can have more control on the files that go into sort by using `find` for example, or the `--include` and `--exclude` `grep` flags.

Comment: No need to specify "1000": if you do `sort -k 2`, then sort will use "from the 2nd field to the end of the line" as the key.

Comment: @glennjackman you are right, corrected.

Comment: great work! thanks